# How to send message to kafka producer using vertx eventbus

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x

I am learning kafka and vertx and I got across the following statements,

1.Kafka module allows to receive events published by other Vert.x verticles and send those events to Kafka broker.

2.Application sends messages to Kafka module using Vertx bus

3.Kafka module acts as a producer

Anyone letting me know how they are programmed, would be very helpful. Thanks.

I found the source code here, but I am looking for an simpler example. https://github.com/zanox/mod-kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Kafka module only acts as a producer - not as a consumer.  So it's intent is to publish messages external (outbound) from the system.  The example on the referenced Github link is very easy to follow, if you follow along with the following Kafka quick start at the same time - http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#quickstart

You don't have to use modules, you can use the Kafka Java client within your Verticles.  Modules are intended as a mechanism for re-use and providing common functionality.

In Vertx 3.0 (next release), the module system is removed anyway.